# Property List get_value undefined erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I am new to erlang. I have property list as follows.

```
[{name,<<"127.0.0.1:53290 -> 127.0.0.1:1883">>},{pid,<0.987.0>},{user,<<"guest">>},{type,direct}]
```

This is my function.

```
close_single_connection(Conn, ReqData) ->
     io:format("~p\n", Conn),
     case proplists:get_value(pid, Conn) of
          undefined -> io:format("Undefined~n"),ok;
          Pid when is_pid(Pid) ->
              io:format(Pid),
              force_close_connection(ReqData, Conn, Pid)
         end.
```

`io:format("~p\n", Conn)` return my property list correctly. But `proplists:get_value(pid, Conn)` return undefined.

When I am executing following in erlang shell it return Pid value correctly.

```
List = [{name,<<"127.0.0.1:53290 -> 127.0.0.1:1883">>},{pid,<0.987.0>},{user,<<"guest">>},{type,direct}],
proplists:get_value(pid, List).
```

Please give me a way to identify the reason.

Comment: It works for me…
```
1> List = [{name,<<"127.0.0.1:53290 -> 127.0.0.1:1883">>},{pid,<0.987.0>},{user,<<"guest">>},{type,direct}], proplists:get_value(pid, List).


<0.987.0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in list creation step.

List should create as follows. This is working properly.

```
List = [],

List ++ [{name,<<"127.0.0.1:53290 -> 127.0.0.1:1883">>},{pid,<0.987.0>},{user,<<"guest">>},{type,direct}].
```

Following is the wrong one. I added redundant [] like this.

```
List = [],

X = [{name,<<"127.0.0.1:53290 -> 127.0.0.1:1883">>},{pid,<0.987.0>},{user,<<"guest">>},{type,direct}],
List ++ [X].
```

Comment: Concatenating a list with the empty list gives back the original list. In the second alternative you are rather creating a list containing another list. Are you sure this is what fixed it?

Comment: @pottu I edited my answer. First one is working example and second one is wrong one. Is my answer correct now ?

Comment: It's corrected in the sense that they aren't said to be equivalent, yes. I wonder still how this solves the problem you had, as the first (correct) list shown here is the same as the one shown in the question. If the second (wrong) list was the one originally used, then you may want to put that in the question instead.

Comment: In my original case I have multiple records (List has multiple X elements). After I add for loop to execute logic with all elements. When I am use first (correct) return added X inside for loop. But when I use second (wrong) one it return [X] instead of X. That is the issue I faced.